# how do I save a ftp password but get the plain password later

Tags: php, hash, ftp, passwords

Okay so,

I have a problem where I need to save a password on a server with my hash with php's crypt hashing function, but I need the plain password to test the users password so he can connect to his own ftp server (with the password he entered)... and I'm stumped for ideas on how to do this...

I was going to create a function that just adds random set of characters into the password and then I would just remove them later when I try to get the plain password... (which is bad I know) but any ideas?

**Question**: 
Is their anyway to save a plain password and be as secure as hashing the password... Like I said above I need to use the plain password to connect to his ftp server, so I can't just compare the hashed passwords...

Thanks in advanced...

Comment: Your question is not easy to answer if you are  using a one-way Hash

Comment: @AaronGong yeah, is there any possible way of doing it even if I didn't do any hashing (just saying probably won't happen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using mysql as your data storage use [DES_ENCRYPT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_des-encrypt)

`[...] SET password = DES_ENCRYPT($password) [...]`

alternatively try [ENCRYPT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_encrypt)

To reverse use DES_DECRYPT or DECRYPT

This way you have passwords stored in a fairly secure way that you can decrypt to use in plaintext at will.